# ¿ Como pongo el formulario en paralelo a los parrafos teniendo bootstrap y estilos propios?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, formularios

Sigo intentando dar funciones a mi web, la cual estoy consiguiendo gracias a los compañeros (@Camilo Vasquez, @Alvaro Montoro, @Pepo Gonzalez)
En este caso, trato de poner el formulario que esta debajo de almohadilla, a la derecha de los cuatro párrafos, paralelo.
¿ Seria eso posible de algún modo, poner el formulario a la derecha de los párrafos, compartiendo ambos el ancho de pagina, dejando margenes entre si y laterales ?
Dejo la muestra de mi código.
Gracias.

```css
/* LA VERDAD ES QUE FUNCIONA CASI TODO GRACIAS A LOS RETOQUES DE Camilo Vasquez, Alvaro Montoro*/
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    color:#444444;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    font:400 16px/1.8 sans-serif;
    }
    
    .nav-navbar-nav{
        font-size: 5;
    
    }
    .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    position:relative;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
    .bgimg-1 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_01.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-2 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_02.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-3 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_03.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:48%;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    background-color:#444444;
    }
    h2 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font:20px sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:4px;
    color:#444444;
    }
    a {
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
      margin-left: 5% !important;
    }
    
    #header{
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1000;
      font-size: 6
    }
    
    .navbar{
      margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }

    .navbar ul li a{
      font-size: 12px
    }
    
    
    /*OTRA LISTA DE ESTILOS*/
    body {
         min-width: 630px;
     }
     
     #container{
         margin-top: 51px;
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: row;
     }
     
     #container .column {
         position: relative;
     }
     
     #footer {
         clear: both;
     }
     
     /* IE hack */
     * html #left {
         left: 150px;
     }
     
     /*Haz que las columnas tengan la misma altura que las otras */
     #container {
         overflow: hidden;
     }
     
     /*Solución para el pie de página */
     * html body {
         overflow: hidden;
     }
     
     * html #footer-wrapper {
         float: left;
         position: relative;
         width: 100%;
         padding-bottom: 10010px;
         margin-bottom: -10000px;
         background: #fff;
     }
     
     /* Aesthetics */
     body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         font-family:Sans-serif;
         line-height: 1.5em;
     }
     
     p {
         color: #555;
     }
     
     nav ul {
         list-style-type: none;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
     }
     
     nav ul a {
         color: darkgreen;
         text-decoration: none;
     }
     
     #header, #footer {
         font-size: large;
         background: #BCCE98;
     }
     
     #left {
         background: #DAE9BC;
     }
     
     #right {
         background: #F7FDEB;
     }
     
     #center {
         background: #fff;
     }
     
     #container .column {
         padding-top: 1em;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">-->
     <link rel="icon" href="imagenes/icon.ico" />

     <!-- ESTOS ENLACES LES TENGO GRACIAS A Camilo Vasquez me sugirio para crear barra de navegacion-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
     <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
     <title>Nueva</title>
     <link href="css/nueva.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="css/todo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


     <!-- AQUI TAMBIEN FORMO PARTE Camilo Vasquez AYUDANDO ME CON LOS BOTONES DE LA BARRA DE NAVEGACION-->
 </head>
 <body>
         <header id="header">
                 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                     <div class="container">
                         <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
                         <div class="navbar-header">
             
                             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                                 Logo
                             </a>
                         </div>
                         <!-- Navbar links -->
                         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                 <li class="active">
                                     <a href="#">PRINCIPAL</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                     <a href="#">SOGRE MI</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                     <a href="#">SOBRE MI</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="dropdown">
                                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SOBRE MI <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
                                         <li><a href="#">ESTUDIOS</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">PROYECTOS</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
                                     </ul>
                                 </li>
                             </ul>
             
                             <!-- Search -->
                             <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                 </div>
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                             </form>
             
                         </div>
                         <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.container -->
                 </nav>
             </header>
             <div id="container">

                 </nav>
             
                 <main id="center" class="column col-md-8">
                     <article>
                     
                         <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
                         <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web, el cual estoy creando mientras realizo un curso de actívate. 
                          En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos que 
                          vaya adquiriendo en el curso. </p>
                                 
                         
                         <P></P>
                         <h2>CURRICULUM</h2>
                         <p>Aquí encontrareis los <a href="curriculum-1.html">trabajos </a>por los que me he movido, siendo el transporte por carretera lo que mas he desempeñado estos 
                                 últimos años. </p>
                         <h2></h2>
                         <h2>ESPEDIENTE ACADEMICO</h2>
                         <p>Mis estudios no son muchos, deje pronto la escuela para trabajar. Pero en los últimos años he retomado el tema académico,
                                 formandome en el tema de la programación y aunque llevo poco tiempo ya he creado alguna <a href="proyectos-4.html">humilde aplicacion.</a></p>
                         
                         <h2>EXPERIENCIA</h2>
             
                         <p>Como ya he dicho, mi carrera de desarrollador no a echo mas que empezar, y son pocos y pequeños los <a href="proyectos-4.html">proyectos </a>que he 
                             creado,   pero estoy dedicandome plenamente en sacar una aplicación que espero tenga una buena aceptación 
                         </p>
                         <h2></h2>
                         <h2></h2>
                 
             

                     
                     </article>                              
                 </main>
             
            
             </div>

             <P>#######################################################################################<br>
            @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</P>
             <main>
                <div class="innertube">
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    <h1>CONSULTAS</h1>
                    
                    <form action="" method="get">
                    <p>
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label> <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="50">
                    </p>
                    
                    <p>
                    <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label> <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" maxlength="50">
                    </p>

                    
                    <p>
                    <label for="correo">Correo:</label> <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" maxlength="100">
                    </p>
                    
                    
                    <p>
                    <label for="poblacion">Población:</label>
                    <select name="poblacion" id="poblacion">
                    <option>Alicante</option>
                    <option>Avila</option>
                    <option>La Parra</option>
                    <option>Madrid</option>
                    <option>Sevilla</option>
                    <option>Valencia</option>
                    </select>
                    </p>
                    
                    <p><label for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
                    <textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="info" id="info" checked="checked"> <label for="info">Deseo recibir información sobre novedades y ofertas</label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="condiciones" id="condiciones"> <label for="condiciones"> Declaro haber leido y aceptar las condiciones generales del programa y la normativa sobre protección de datos</label>
                    </p>
                    
                    <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
                    </p>
                    </form>
                    
                    
                    <!--<p><script>generateText(300)</script></p>-->
                    
                </div>
            </main>
             
         <div id="footer-wrapper">
                 <footer id="footer"><p>Footer...</p></footer>
             </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problemas/Recomendaciones del código:

- Tienes un `</nav>` huérfano que puede causarte problemas. Bórralo.
- Tienes más de un `<main>`. Aunque esto técnicamente no es un problema, sería recomendable dejarlo en uno para este caso.
- Las columnas (`col-*-*`) deberían dentro de un `.row` para que se ajusten mejor (esto se debe a cómo están definidas y sus márgenes). Deberías familiarizarte con el sistema de *grid* de Bootstrap. Crea un `<div class="row">` que envuelva el `<main>` de los párrafos.
- Como los párrafos están dentro de un `<main>` que ocupa 8 columnas (por la clase `col-md-8`), mueve el `<main>` del formulario a justo después del `<main>` de los párrafos y haz que ocupe 4 columnas añadiéndole la clase `col-md-4`.

Y ya está, Bootstrap se encargará de ponerlo automáticamente a la derecha con el formato correcto. Con esos cambios, el código queda así:

```css
/* LA VERDAD ES QUE FUNCIONA CASI TODO GRACIAS A LOS RETOQUES DE Camilo Vasquez, Alvaro Montoro*/

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #444444;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.8 sans-serif;
}

.nav-navbar-nav {
  font-size: 5;
}

.bgimg-1,
.bgimg-2,
.bgimg-3 {
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url("../imagenes/bg_01.jpg");
  height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-2 {
  background-image: url("../imagenes/bg_02.jpg");
  height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-3 {
  background-image: url("../imagenes/bg_03.jpg");
  height: 100%;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 48%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  background-color: #444444;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 20px sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #444444;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin-left: 5% !important;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 6
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 12px
}


/*OTRA LISTA DE ESTILOS*/

body {
  min-width: 630px;
}

#container {
  margin-top: 51px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#container .column {
  position: relative;
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
}


/* IE hack */

* html #left {
  left: 150px;
}


/*Haz que las columnas tengan la misma altura que las otras */

#container {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Solución para el pie de página */

* html body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

* html #footer-wrapper {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10010px;
  margin-bottom: -10000px;
  background: #fff;
}


/* Aesthetics */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

p {
  color: #555;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
  color: darkgreen;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header,
#footer {
  font-size: large;
  background: #BCCE98;
}

#left {
  background: #DAE9BC;
}

#right {
  background: #F7FDEB;
}

#center {
  background: #fff;
}

#container .column {
  padding-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">-->
  <link rel="icon" href="imagenes/icon.ico" />

  <!-- ESTOS ENLACES LES TENGO GRACIAS A Camilo Vasquez me sugirio para crear barra de navegacion-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <title>Nueva</title>
  <link href="css/nueva.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/todo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- AQUI TAMBIEN FORMO PARTE Camilo Vasquez AYUDANDO ME CON LOS BOTONES DE LA BARRA DE NAVEGACION-->
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Logo
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#">PRINCIPAL</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">SOGRE MI</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">SOBRE MI</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SOBRE MI <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
                <li><a href="#">ESTUDIOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PROYECTOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Search -->
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
          </form>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="container">

    <div class="row">
      <main id="center" class="column col-md-8">
        <article>

          <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
          <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web, el cual estoy creando mientras realizo un curso de actívate. En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos que vaya
            adquiriendo en el curso. </p>


          <P></P>
          <h2>CURRICULUM</h2>
          <p>Aquí encontrareis los <a href="curriculum-1.html">trabajos </a>por los que me he movido, siendo el transporte por carretera lo que mas he desempeñado estos últimos años. </p>
          <h2></h2>
          <h2>ESPEDIENTE ACADEMICO</h2>
          <p>Mis estudios no son muchos, deje pronto la escuela para trabajar. Pero en los últimos años he retomado el tema académico, formandome en el tema de la programación y aunque llevo poco tiempo ya he creado alguna <a href="proyectos-4.html">humilde aplicacion.</a></p>

          <h2>EXPERIENCIA</h2>

          <p>Como ya he dicho, mi carrera de desarrollador no a echo mas que empezar, y son pocos y pequeños los <a href="proyectos-4.html">proyectos </a>que he creado, pero estoy dedicandome plenamente en sacar una aplicación que espero tenga una buena
            aceptación
          </p>
          <h2></h2>
          <h2></h2>




        </article>
      </main>


      <main class=" col-md-4">
        <div class="innertube">

          <h1>CONSULTAS</h1>

          <form action="" method="get">
            <p>
              <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label> <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="50">
            </p>

            <p>
              <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label> <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" maxlength="50">
            </p>


            <p>
              <label for="correo">Correo:</label> <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" maxlength="100">
            </p>


            <p>
              <label for="poblacion">Población:</label>
              <select name="poblacion" id="poblacion">
                    <option>Alicante</option>
                    <option>Avila</option>
                    <option>La Parra</option>
                    <option>Madrid</option>
                    <option>Sevilla</option>
                    <option>Valencia</option>
                    </select>
            </p>

            <p><label for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
              <textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="checkbox" name="info" id="info" checked="checked"> <label for="info">Deseo recibir información sobre novedades y ofertas</label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="checkbox" name="condiciones" id="condiciones"> <label for="condiciones"> Declaro haber leido y aceptar las condiciones generales del programa y la normativa sobre protección de datos</label>
            </p>

            <p>
              <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
            </p>
          </form>


          <!--<p><script>generateText(300)</script></p>-->

        </div>
      </main>

    </div>

  </div>

  <P>#######################################################################################<br> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  </P>


  <div id="footer-wrapper">
    <footer id="footer">
      <p>Footer...</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, muy buena explicacion con ella podre hacer ancho el formulario. He buscado sobre tu consejo sobre sistema grid, y encontre lo siguiente, no se si habra algo mejor para estudiarme: https://openwebinars.net/blog/tutorial-bootstrap-3-sistema-grid/                                 Muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: He descubierto que tengo un problema, al darle margin-left a la seccion de parrafos, el formulario se mueve de  nuevo debajo de los parrafos.                          ¿Como podria dar margen al main (parrafos) sin que suceda esto...?      
 Gracias.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso En lugar de usar `margin` usa `padding`. De ese modo el espacio se encuentra ahí pero no afecta el ancho. Aparte, quizás te interesa poner un `class="container"` al `div` con id container.

Comment: Gracias, estoy probando con el pading, pero no me esta saliendo muy bien, a ver si lo consigo. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: pruebo con el pading y no funciona muy bien, se abre un margen a la derecha del formulario muy amplio. Y no me queda muy clara tu idea de poner un class="container" al div con id container. Un saludo

Comment: Sobre `container`: en Bootstrap hay una clase `.container` que hace que el contenido se ajuste automáticamente a ciertos anchos de pantalla. En el código compartido tienes un `div id="container"` y me pregunto si lo que quieres hacer realmente es un `div class="container"`

Comment: Quiza esa sea la solucion, con las columnas no logro dejar las dos partes al 50% y a su vez dejar un margen igual a la izquierda, derecha y entre.                        Seguire intentando y probando. Gracias

Comment: Para dejar las columnas al 50% les tienes que dar un ancho de 6

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68982/discussion-between-alvaro-montoro-and-miguel-espeso).